# Error in communiction between salt-minion and salt-master

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I have installed a minion and a master on 2 ec2 instances and started configuring them using the file doc provided in saltstack (below link)
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/index.html

then i came up with an error like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pK6Z.png)

Comment: Can you tell us which version of salt-minion/master you are using?

Comment: Also, can you show output of ```ps -aux | grep "salt-minion"```.  I've had an issue where salt-minion was running multiple instances, and I had to kill those before running debugging.